# In bacterial conjugation, how do F+/F- cells detect each other?

Tags: microbiology, sexual-reproduction

I've just learnt about bacterial conjugation and while it is interesting info about early sexual activity in microbes, one aspect confuses me and doesnt seem to be mentioned in the material I read:

How do the donor/recipient pairs find each other?

While cells in a culture all can have physical contact as they move about, either the F+ cell inserts pili into various cells looking for some chemical stimulus or physical contact with a F- cell provides some data that lets it know it has touched a cell with which it can now perform conjugation.

Comment: F+ cells have mechanisms in place that inhibit them from making contacting with other F+ cells, therefore, a F plasmid cannot be transferred from F+ to F+. Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21351/